# Not Displaying Properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I need to display all the inputs in one column, but this displays in multiple columns.

I have tried changing the syntax but it's not working:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spStringSplit
    @String1 NVARCHAR(255),
    @String2 NVARCHAR(255),
    @String3 NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @String1
    SELECT @String2
    SELECT @String3
END
GO

EXEC spStringSplit 'a','b','c'
```

What I need is:

```
ColName
--------
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a recent version of SQL Server, you can use `VALUES`.

(The syntax is a bit convoluted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        VALUES
        ( @String1 ),
        ( @String2 ),
        ( @String3 )
    )
```

In older versions of SQL Server you'll need to use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT
    @String1 AS Col1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    @String2 AS Col1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    @String3 AS Col1
```

Comment: The Second One Worked. Thanks !

Comment: you missed the alias for the 1st query

Comment: The [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) has been around for quite a long time in tsql.